# numpy resampling reshape data

Tags: numpy, sample, convolution, smoothing

I convolved a specific 1D size data set and the output was a larger 1D dataset. Is there a way to resample the data to the original size before convolving?

Here is what I used to convolve that data
Kp1smo=np.convolve(Kp1,np.ones(5)/5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the output of the convolution to be the same size as the input **Kp1** you could do the convolution using the 'same' option:

```
Kp1smo=np.convolve(Kp1,np.ones(5)/5),'same')
```

According to [the documentation for numpy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) this will return  a result of size max(M,N), where M and N are the size of the two input vectors. If Kp1 is larger than 5 this will be the size of Kp1.

With no argument, numpy.convolve defaults to 'full' mode which gives a result of size (N+M-1)